# Eclipse Maven Web Project Servlet Mappings

Tags: eclipse, servlets, tomcat7, web.xml, m2e

I have set up my maven project using the m2e plugin in eclipse indigo, and transformed it to an eclipse dynamic web project using `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=1.5`. I have managed to get the project up and running in tomcat7, except for my servlets, for which I cannot create the servlet mappings.

I have tried modifying the web.xml file but it throws a ClassNotFoundException. Directory Structure and web.xml :

```
(ROOT)
    +src
       +main
          +resources
              +DrawInitialMap.java
          +webapp
               (WebContent here)


<web-app>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>DrawInitialMap</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>(groupId).(artifactId).src.main.resources.DrawInitialMap</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>DrawInitialMap</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/drawInitialMap.do</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
  (...)
</web-app>
```

While the @WebServlet annotation also fails to map the servlet :

```
@WebServlet(name="drawInitialMap", description="visualizes ttrp on html5 canvas", urlPatterns={"/drawInitialMap.do"})
```

Thank you in advance, and notify if you need any more of the code.

PS : Keep in mind that the servlet worked perfectly in Dynamic Web Project mode, without Maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues.

1. You should stop using eclipse:eclipse. Instead, install [WTP integration for M2E](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) from Eclipse Marketplace
2. In Maven project, your DrawInitialMap should be in /src/main/classes folder. So, it will be compiled as per default Maven project conventions
3. The servlet-class element in web.xml requires full class name, i.e. no things like (groupId).(artifactId).src.main.resources.

Comment: Yes, the problem was like you said on item #3. Thank you :)